# How to use create-react-cli for components without creating a folder for each

Tags: reactjs

I'd like each new component to just be in src/Components instead of src/components/newComponent. This would simplify imports from src/components/newComponent/newComponent to src/components/newComponent as well.

I'm not currently creating css or test files for each component, so having a folder for each single file is cluttered.

I've tried to find answers here and on the github page https://github.com/arminbro/generate-react-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, it's the flag --flat that I'm looking for.

Comment: It looks like this isn't currently working, however: https://github.com/arminbro/generate-react-cli/issues/71

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/arminbro/generate-react-cli, you can change the default path from "generate-react-cli.json"

```
"component": {
"default": {
  "path": "src/components",
```

to this

```
"component": {
"default": {
  "path": "src",
```

or any folder what you want